# Passing Data to Windows in Electron

Tags: electron

I'm learning Electron and working with multiple windows and IPC. In my main script I have the following:

```
var storeWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 400,
  height: 400,
  show: false
});

ipc.on('show-store-edit', function(event, store) {
  console.log(store);
  storeWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/app/store.html');
  storeWindow.show();
});
```

And in my primary window's script, I have the following inside of a click event handler, pulling in a list of stores:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/stores/" + item.id).done(function(store) {
   ipc.send('show-store-edit', store);
});
```

On the console, I am printing the store data from my server. What I'm unclear on is how to get that data into the view for my `storeWindow:store.html`. I'm not even sure I'm handling the sequence of events correctly but they would be:

- click Edit Store
- get store data from server
- open new window to display store data

or

- click Edit Store
- open new window to display store data
- get store data from server

In the latter, I'm not sure how I would get the ID required to fetch the store from the `storeWindow's` script.

Comment: You can use `storeWindow.webContents.send(EVENT_NAME, ARGS)` ([docs](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.37.6/api/web-contents/#webcontentssendchannel-arg1-arg2-)) to send data to particular window. You also have to add a listener in window process  - `ipcRenderer.on(EVENT_NAME, function (ARGS) {});`

Answer (score 90, accepted):

To send events to particular window you can use `webContents.send(EVENT_NAME, ARGS)` ([see docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentssendchannel-arg1-arg2-)). `webContents` is a property of a window instance:

```
// main process
storeWindow.webContents.send('store-data', store);
```

To listen for this event being sent, you need a listener in a window process (renderer):

```
// renderer process
var ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
ipcRenderer.on('store-data', function (event,store) {
    console.log(store);
});
```

Comment: Where is the `ipcRenderer` defined?

Comment: @Hackjutsu, it is provided by electron package. You can import it like this: `var ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;` or es6 `import { ipcRenderer } from 'electron';`

Comment: Do you know if arguments are passed as references, or if the renderer creates a new reference? For instance, if you are passing a large amount of data, are we going to end-up with duplicate references for all of the data and; therefore, a double tax on memory?

Comment: @JohnGalt I am not entirely sure, but my guess is that it works similar to web workers `postMessage`. Main and renderer processes are ... well... different processes, and my thought is that all the data is being serialized to a string on one side, then sent through communication channel, and then deserialized on the other side, which means that the content will be re-created, therefore there won't be any direct reference. But again, that's my wild guess, you'd better check how it works in your code by simply sending an object and trying to change it from another process.

Comment: it may be important which event you send the message from if in the main process. I found something like this to be helpful:

`term.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
      console.log("now sendding a message to term window");
        term.webContents.send('start-session', arg)
    })
`

Answer (score 12):

**You need the ipcMain module to achieve this... As stated in the API "When used in the main process, it handles asynchronous and synchronous messages sent from a renderer process (web page). Messages sent from a renderer will be emitted to this module."**

**API Docs for the ipcMain module:**
https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main

To use the ipcMain you need to have **nodeIntegration** enabled on **webPreferences**

```
win = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
    }
})
```

*Be careful this may cause security issues.*

For example: Let's say we want to pass a configuration (json) file to the web page

*(Triple dots (...) represent your code that is already placed inside the file, but is not relevant to this example)*

**main.js**

```
...

const { readFileSync } = require('fs') // used to read files
const { ipcMain } = require('electron') // used to communicate asynchronously from the main process to renderer processes.
...

// function to read from a json file
function readConfig () {
  const data = readFileSync('./package.json', 'utf8')
  return data
}

...
// this is the event listener that will respond when we will request it in the web page
ipcMain.on('synchronous-message', (event, arg) => {
  console.log(arg)
  event.returnValue = readConfig()
})
...
```

**index.html**

```
...    
<script>
    <!-- import the module -->
    const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

    <!-- here we request our message and the event listener we added before, will respond and because it's JSON file we need to parse it -->
    var config = JSON.parse(ipcRenderer.sendSync('synchronous-message', ''))

    <!-- process our data however we want, in this example we print it on the browser console -->
    console.log(config)

     <!-- since we read our package.json file we can echo our electron app name -->
     console.log(config.name)
</script>
```

*To see the console of the browser you need to open the dev tools, either from the default Electron menu or from your code.*
e.g. inside the createWindow() function

```
 win.webContents.openDevTools()
```